# Serialize XML and append new elements to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, append

I have created a XML class using XSD2Code from my XML Schema. The class having a method SaveToFile. So when I am trying to add new elements and save it to the XML file it overwrites the entire content.

Does anyone have idea how to insert elements(append to the XML) to the XML file via Serialization.

eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <element>content1</element>
</root>
```

If this is the XML file I need to add an element and the resulting should come as like below using Serialization.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <element>content1</element>
  <element>content2</element>
</root>
```

Comment: If you serialize something it's supposed to make an XML representation of the object you're serializing so adding elements that are not in your object makes no sense when serializing?

Comment: cant you add new element to your root class elements and then save it to xml file? Something like that: `yourRootClassInstance.elementsArray.Add(new element());`

Comment: My primary purpose is to add new values to the XML file using the Class which I generated from Schema. How Can I do that. Class is using List for collection object.

Comment: It would be better to show generated class code. In that class should be list of element objects. If so like I wrote above you need to add new element to that array

Answer (score 0):

Your request would seem to be resolvable by adding another item into your List collection.

```
MyTypeFromXmlSchema myType = new MyTypeFromXmlSchema();
myType.MyElementItems = new List<MyElementItem>();
myType.MyElementItems.Add { new MyElementItem { value = "value1" } };
myType.MyElementItems.Add { new MyElementItem { value = "value2" } };
```

Then serialize type using XmlSerializer.