# Append Serialized Object Into XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a XML structer like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product>
  <ProductName>da</ProductName>
  <PluginPath></PluginPath>
  <Instances></Instances>
</Product>
```

and i serialize my object to string.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Instance xmlns:xsi="http://bla bla" xmlns:xsd="bla bla" UniqueId="d4820029b7d7">
<InstanceName>Instance MyTestPluginForm</InstanceName>
<Description>Test Plugin IW</Description>
<AddedDate>2016-10-19T11:05:10.7443404+02:00</AddedDate>
<LogSettings>
<LoggingLevel>None</LoggingLevel>
<LogFilePath /><MaximumSize>100</MaximumSize
<ClearAfterDays>7</ClearAfterDays>
<IsSaveActiviesToEventLog>false</IsSaveActiviesToEventLog>
</LogSettings>
<ProductSpecific/>
</Instance>
```

So I want to append the second one in the Instances node in the first xml. But as you see both has xml definition on the top and after serializazion i got xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd attributes.

How to solve this problem?

PS: I do not want to create XML elements. Because my xml schema is dynamic. It has to be done with serialization. (I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703782/serialize-xml-and-append-new-elements-to-xml-file) sample)

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I solved it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811865/how-to-append-xml-data-into-xml-file)

```
    public static void CreateXmlFile(Instance instance, string filePath)
    {

       var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Product><ProductName>da</ProductName><PluginPath></PluginPath><Instances></Instances></Product>";



        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
        xmlDocument.Save(filePath);


        XmlNode xnode = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Instances", null);
        XmlSerializer xSeriz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Instance));
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        XmlWriterSettings writtersetting = new XmlWriterSettings();
        writtersetting.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
        using (XmlWriter xmlwriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(stringwriter, writtersetting))
        {
            xSeriz.Serialize(xmlwriter, instance, ns);
        }
        xnode.InnerXml = stringwriter.ToString();
        XmlNode bindxnode = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Instance");
        xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Instances").AppendChild(bindxnode);
        xmlDocument.Save(filePath);

    }
```